# Convert a list with characters to a string (Python)

Tags: python, string, list, spi

i am trying to read a sting via the SPI port on the Raspberry Pi. This is my code to test the port:

```
raw = 0
string = ""

SPI = spidev.SpiDev()
SPI.open(0,0)

while True:
    raw = SPI.xfer2([0])
    string += str(chr(raw))
    print string
    print raw
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

The result is "Hell*insert gibberish*" so it fails after the fourth character. I try to send "Hello World!" The data I send is formatted as character in the list, for example "Hello" will look like [72, 101, 108, 108, 111]. How do I convert this to a string?

The answers were useful, as I did not know how to convert the data. The real problem however was with the device I was interfacing with. The answers were useful in finding the real problem, so many thanks! I am still fairly new to python so these things are kind of a hassle to get into.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either use [`bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bytearray) or [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) with [`chr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr):

```
>>> lst =  [72, 101, 108, 108, 111]
>>> str(bytearray(lst))
'Hello'
#or
>>> ''.join(chr(x) for x in lst)
'Hello'
```

Answer (score 1):

If I get this right, you want to convert  [72, 101, 108, 108, 111] to 'Hello'?

```
data = [72, 101, 108, 108, 111]
string = "".join([chr(n) for n in data])
print string
```

Output:

```
Hello
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider also appending converted characters to a string, like this,

```
str = ""
for c in [chr(n) for n in lst]:
    str += c
```

**Update**

In a functional programming style, as follows,

```
from functools import reduce
reduce( (lambda x,y: x + chr(y)), [72, 101, 108, 108, 111], "")
```

where `reduce` applies the lambda function to each item in the list, starting from the empty string (last argument). The lambda function can be defined this way,

```
def append(str,n): return str + chr(n)
```

and so the call to `reduce` becomes lesser verbose,

```
reduce( append, [72, 101, 108, 108, 111], "")
'Hello'
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I need to read strings of unknown lengths! great!